# Use isinstance on type variable

Tags: python

I have a class defined with a generic

```
T= TypeVar("T")
class D(Generic[T]):
     
    def get_data(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, T):
            pass

D[int]().get_data(3) # will throw
```

I'm trying to check if an object passed to a function is of type T, however this doesn't work.
Is there a way to do something similar ?

Comment: No. Generally (although not always) type annotations will not be actual types, which is what `isinstance` will require

Comment: One recent exceptions is passing a union type, but that union must consist of real types, not just type annotations

Comment: You can use `isinstance(d, get_args(self.__orig_class__))` starting from python 3.8. Docs: [`typing.get_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args).